# How to set regression intercept to 0 in Orange

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, orange, orange-api

I wrote the bellow regression code in python using orange library but

```
import Orange
data = Orange.data.Table("lenses")
learner = Orange.regression.LinearRegressionLearner()
model = learner(data)
print (model.coefficients)
```

I need to set intercept to zero and I found this code

```
__init__(name=linear regression, intercept=True, compute_stats=True, ridge_lambda=None, imputer=None, continuizer=None, use_vars=None, stepwise=False, add_sig=0.05, remove_sig=0.2, **kwds)
```

in this page: http://orange.biolab.si/docs/latest/reference/rst/Orange.regression.linear.html
but I don not know how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set intercept=False.

```
learner = Orange.regression.LinearRegressionLearner(intercept=False)
```

Comment: I added this code but i got following error:   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Taha Mokfi/Desktop/new1.py", line 3, in <module>
    learner = Orange.regression.LinearRegressionLearner(intercept=False)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'intercept'

Comment: Are you sure you are have installed latest Orange library? Because I need to have different import for the LinearRegressionLearner.  I need to do this, learner = Orange.regression.linear.LinearRegressionLearner(intercept=True)

Comment: My orange version is 3.2 and I am using Python 3.4.3. does this code work for you? what is your orange library version? what is your python version?

Comment: My bad, I think I am using old Orange version. Installing the new one. By the way, why not use [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html)

Comment: I am trying to compare the precision of estimation in orange. By the way I am here to hear from others :) thanks @Sagar